# Process this output of an off-the-shelf pressure sensor

Tags: sensors, software, signal-processing

I'm a software engineer working on theoretical things in my daily work. Lately I wanted to connect a pressure sensor, like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WCPNTT9), to a digital device that I can program, so that I can constantly read pressure sensors output and then do stuff depending on what pressure data I read in.

I was thinking about going for the Arduino for that, but feel free to suggest alternatives, as I don't have prior experience with Arduino so far.

In the link above it only says "Output signal: analog". I have unfortunately no education in electrical engineering so my question is if can I connect such a sensor to Arduino (or similar devices)? Do I need to do some soldering?
I guess that there must be some kind of protocol that the output signal must adhere to (I have read Arduino support GPIO)?

Sensor part number in case link dies: RP-S40 Thin Film Pressure Sensor

Comment: The link tells you how the resistance changes with load. Even shows a couple of diagrams. What else do you expect? Them to send you an engineer included in the price?

Comment: IIRC, Arduino has analog input. Find out the voltage range of Arduino analog input and the voltage range of Pressure sensor analog output and check if the latter *fits within* the range of the former.

Comment: @SolarMike No need to be so confrontational - I asked here on this forum precisely because I wasn't clear about the meaning of those things.

Comment: Do a search for Data loggers, there are lots of options, even pressure data loggers packaged up already which might be a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can connect that device to an arduino. Try the left circuit in the second picture first (simple voltage divider). It's the simplest and should work ok unless you need high accuracy.

The device acts electrically as a resistor, and the output signal is the resistance. Some ballpark specs for this are provided, but if you want a lot of detail you need to buy legit parts from suppliers like digikey, not no-name stuff from amazon.

You should expect to do some soldering. It's almost always required when working with small electronics. I won't detail how to get started with that here, just search it, it's cheap, and not very hard.

An arduino is a good choice for getting started with microcontrollers. There is a lot of support available, and the ide, although simplistic works ok without a lot of toolchain setup.

Comment: Thanks, will look up the soldering, no worries. Also thanks about the tip regarding digikey, An Arduino can simply accept all kinds of loads (if that is the correct word?) I connect to it? Somehow from software engineering I am used to always look for matching protocols, but not much seems to be needed here for that.

Comment: Some protocols are implemented in hardware (i2c spi, serial, etc) and exposed on certain pins (which can alternatively be used as GPIO). Your sensor is analog though and the signal is simple enough that the arduino doesn't need to know anything about it in order to read it. A resistor is a resistor.